# Store Procedure doesnt get executed. DataSet returns nothing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have this store procedure in my db:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[AddUpdateCams]
@CamImage_UID uniqueidentifier = NULL,
@CamImage_Url1 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CamImage_Url2 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CamImage_StatusID int = 10,
@CamImage_ItemNr nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CamImage_OrderNr nvarchar(50) = NULL

as 
 begin
 set nocount on;
 if @CamImage_UID is null
  begin
  set @CamImage_UID = NEWID()

insert into dbo.CamImage (CamImage_UID,CamImage_Url1, CamImage_Url2, 
CamImage_StatusID, CamImage_CreateDate, CamImage_ItemNr, CamImage_OrderNr)
values (@CamImage_UID, @CamImage_Url1, @CamImage_Url2, @CamImage_StatusID, 
GETDATE(), @CamImage_ItemNr, @CamImage_OrderNr)
 end

else 
 begin
  update CamImage 
  set CamImage_StatusID = @CamImage_StatusID
  where CamImage_UID = @CamImage_UID
  end

select * from CamImage where CamImage_UID = @CamImage_UID
end
```

I am trying to execute this store procedure by using SqlDataAdapter and DataSet, however when executed, my DataSet does not return anything and the problem doesnt seem to be in the Store Procedure because if I executed through sql studio, it doesnt run into any problems.

```
 public DataSet runSPDataSet(string _storedProcedure)
    {
        DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
        if (validateSP(_storedProcedure))
        {
            SqlConnection _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            SqlCommand _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(_storedProcedure, _sqlConnection);
            _sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if(_sqlParameters.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in _sqlParameters)
                {
                    _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(item.ParameterName, item.SqlDbType).Value = item.Value;
                }
            }
            SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_sqlCommand);
            try
            {
                _sqlConnection.Open();
                _sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);
                return _dataSet;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                _sqlConnection.Dispose();
            }              
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Side note, you really should wrap your connection and command objects in a USING statement (and any other objects that inherit IDisposable). That will ensure that they are always properly closed and disposed of correctly.

Comment: Not sure how we can help here. You said the procedure runs fine in SSMS. Your code here is a generic execution for a stored procedure which requires a string being passed in and the parameter collection is outside this method. We can't do much from here because it requires runtime values to interpret. Set some break points and look at your command and parameters. Are they correct? Run a sql trace and see what is actually being executed on your instance.

Comment: And what code is calling this? Do you have an empty try catch in that code? Maybe this is throwing an exception? There are so many things that could be wrong...

Comment: Agree with @SeanLange we can't really assist with debugging. Is the _storedprocedure argument the correct procedure? Are you actually passing NULL as a parameter? Check the db for a record with an empty string as the CamImage_UID. Maybe it's getting updated repeatedly and that behavior looks like the sproc is doing nothing?

Comment: I might be wrong, but can stored procedures return complex data? Don't we need `output` parameters for everything thats not an integer (status code). SSMS prints the result of the query since it prints everything, its not the actual result of the stored procedure...

Comment: @Michael not sure where you came up with that notion. A stored procedure absolutely can return a result set. In fact, it can return multiple result sets but that is not a great practice and a pain to deal with.

Comment: Sprocs can definitely return datasets that can be used in .NET apps.

Comment: @SeanLange Seems to be my fault... :( Does `ExecuteNonQuery` support Datasets as result?

Comment: @Michael no. The return from ExecuteNonQuery is an int which is the number of rows affected. But you absolutely can get result sets from a stored procedure. One example would be to the ExecuteReader method of the Command object.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @SeanLange I have a method that disposes and closes the connection which is called after being done with it. The method is indeed generic, I have tried breakpointing through it and all the parameters are being sent correctly. The SqlCommand.Properties list also gets populated successfully but  something goes wrong when the  _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet) is called.
In addition, I dont have an empty try-catch in the method that is calling this.
On a side note, if I try to run my code with just a basic select query, the DataSet returns data

Comment: I think you missed the point of the USING statement. But whatever you can do this how you like. The issue is we can't help much here because there is a LOT of missing information. Like the parameters, the code that calls this method, the procedure you are calling, etc....I don't like the notion of a generic stored procedure method like this. It is very challenging to get it correct in all situations. The dotnet code to call a procedure is so simple anyway that I prefer to just call it directly.